# TypeError: ufunc 'invert' not supported for the input types

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to drop rows in my dataframe

**The column**

```
Field:FacilityCode
mama100
mimba190
mama1
mimba67
```

```
#delete invalid code from df
df = df[~df['Field:FacilityCode'].str.len()>8] | df[~df['Field:FacilityCode'].str.len()>7]
```

expected output

```
Field:FacilityCode
mama100
mimba190
```

here is the error

```
TypeError: ufunc 'invert' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe'''
```

How can I fix it??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because if length if greater like `7` it means is greater like `8` solution should be simplify - get all rows if length is less or equal `7`:

```
df = df[df['Field:FacilityCode'].str.len()<=7]
```

But your solution is possible:

```
df[~(df['Field:FacilityCode'].str.len()>8) | ~(df['Field:FacilityCode'].str.len()>7)]
```

EDIT: From output data condition is `>7` for filter equal or higher like `7`:

```
df = df[df['Field:FacilityCode'].str.len()>=7]

print (df)
  Field:FacilityCode
0            mama100
1           mimba190
3            mimba67
```

Comment: I have tried to make my question clearer by adding more details

Comment: `df[df['Field:FacilityCode'].str.len()>=7]` failed?

Comment: Thanks..I had not removed  ```~```   ```df = df[~df['Field:FacilityCode'].str.len()<=7]```
It worked